# apex code to send a post request for given information

Tags: rest-api, integration, post

Im trying to write an apex code for a post request while using the below data
this is basically for creating a room in chat tool

```
curl -X PUT -H 'X-ChatWorkToken: Your API token' -d
'description=group+chat+description&icon_preset=meeting&name=Website+renewal+project'
'https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/{room_id)
```

code until now

```
public class groupcreate {
    public static HttpResponse makePostCallout() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/{5678)';
        request.setMethod('POST');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        return response;
    }        
}
```

need some guidance regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-H` is a header to send, `-d` is the data to send, `-X` is the method to use. So:

```
public class groupcreate {
    public static HttpResponse makePostCallout() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/5678';
        request.setHeader('X-ChatWorkToken','Your API token');
        request.setBody('description=group+chat+description&icon_preset=meeting&name=Website+renewal+project');
        request.setMethod('PUT');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        return response;
    }        
}
```

Note: based on the documentation, I'm fairly certain the `{}` do not belong in the URL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply
the program is executing but the result Im looking for is not successful yet i.e creating a room in chatworks
is there any problem in the code?

Comment: @Tejas To create, It looks like you need `POST` and `https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms` instead of a chat room ID (you don't have an ID yet, because the room is not yet created). See [documentation](https://developer.chatwork.com/vi/endpoint_rooms.html#POST-rooms)

Comment: yes i tried that but then too it doesn't seem to work. Im working on API for first time that's why I'm asking - only writing this code in a execution window and running the code will de the job or something else is also required?

Comment: @Tejas In general, yes, that should work. You may need to contact their support directly if you're not able to figure it out.

Comment: tried various things but not working yet....i will try and contact them if not working